# Checkebox com dados do Banco de Dados

Tags: php, mysql

**Reformulei a Pergunta Pessoal**

Preciso que ao atualizar veiculo, seja apresentado todos os motoristas que podem conduzir o veiculo,( assim como na tabela de cadastrar), mas marcando os que foram escolhidos pelo usuario no momento de cadastrar.

Cadastrar o veiculo eu consigo, mas não estou sabendo como atualizar. Não estou sabendo como mostrar os CHECBOX selecionados e salvos no BD.

Tentei usar a logica do IF, comparando se id_motorista da tabela veiculo_motorista, for igual ao id da tabela motorista. Se for verdade, então a variavel $estado receberia o valor de "checked", demostrando assim que aquele CHECBOX foi marcado no momento do cadastrado pelo usuario. Ou seja, se IF for verdadeiro.

Mas lógica de comparação n tá dando certo, estou errando.
Lembrando que todos os id são numeros inteiros.

Segue abaixo o código e imagens.
Agradeço qq ajuda

Tenho tenho 3 tabelas.
tb_veiculos, tb_motoristas, tb_vei_mot.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**SELECAO DE VEICULOS **
<?php
//include_once 'a_conexao.php';
include "IMPORTS/conexao.inc";

```
                 $veiculos = "SELECT veiculo.id, veiculo.placa, vei_mot.motorista FROM veiculo
                 LEFT JOIN vei_mot
                 ON(vei_mot.veiculo=veiculo.id)
                 WHERE veiculo.id='1'" ;

                 $sel_veiculos = mysqli_query($conexao, $veiculos);
                  while($res_sel_veiculos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_veiculos)){                         
                    echo $res_sel_veiculos['placa']."</br>";
                    echo $res_sel_veiculos['motorista']."</br>";
                }   
                
        ?>
```

**SELECAO DE MOTORISTAS **

```
 <?php
                 $motorista = "SELECT id AS id_motorista, nome FROM motorista";
                 $sel_motorista = mysqli_query($conexao, $motorista);
               ?>
               <td> 
                <?php
                  $estado;
                  while($res_sel_motoristas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_motorista)){  
                    if(($res_sel_veiculos['motorista'])==1){
                        $estado="checked" ;                          
                    }else{
                        $estado="" ; 
                    }     
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='motorista[]' value=".$res_sel_motoristas['id_motorista']."  $estado/>".$res_sel_motoristas['nome']."</br>";
                }                   
               ?>                   
               </td>
               </tr>
```

Comment: $selecao['motorista'])=='1', esse 1 está armazenado como que tipo de dado tabela? String, número, booleano... É possível que $selecao['motorista'])==1 resolva. Complemente a pergunta com mais informações sobre as tabelas e dados.

Comment: Todos os ids estão guardados como numeros, tipo inteiro. E cada numero de id, representa um motorista ou um veiculo. NO BD, tabela motorista, id 01 é o motorista joão, id 02 é o roberto. Da msm forma na tabela veiculos, id 01, veiculo PCC0440, id 02 veiculo RRF5544.

Comment: Eu queria entender a logica correta p fazer o CHECBOX ser marcado caso o item motorista seja igual ao id_motorista da tabela veiculos, onde tem todos os motoristas. Trazer os dados eu consigo, mas essa logica simples de se id_motorista for igual a 1, checked em chebox n deu certo.

Comment: Se está como inteiro, a comparação é sem aspas (aspas seria para string, por exemplo) no número um: ($selecao['motorista'])==1 e no echo tem que usar o $estado, não o $situacao. O $situacao não faz nada nesse parte do código. Verifica o código com mais calma e atenção, tem mais coisas para melhorar.

Comment: evite usar imagens de código, coloque o texto do código que formatado fica muito melhor para visualizar, lembre-se que algumas pessoas acessam do mobile e as imagens podem ficar muito pequenas

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, o teu if está errado.
Ele deveria estar escrito assim:

```
if(($selecao['id'])=='1'){
    $estado="checked" ;  
 }else{
    $estado="" ;  
 }
```

Tem mais um erro que vi agora, no teu echo. Ele está chamando a variável errada para dar o checked ou não. Deveria estar assim:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='motorista[]' value=".$id."  $estado/>".$nome."</br>";
```

Comment: Eu corrigir o codigo. Pd rever por favor? Ainda n encontrei a solução